# Wordpress users are not in the database but can login and use the site

Tags: sql, wordpress

So a user signs up to my website. They can login and interact with the site, make posts ect... I cannot find the users in my database in phpmyadmin. I have been told they are in wp_users but there is only test accounts which is weird not even my admin account is there. I have checked every table in the database my WordPress users are not there. Even if i create an account in wordpress they dont show up in wp_users. Can someone please explain where they might be stored?

[image]

Comment: Are you looking in the correct database?

Comment: yes there is only 1 database

Comment: Do you use any kind of plugin that manages users?